# Chrome does not display background-color for a single child of an absolute positioned element with z-index and overflow scrolling

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have created the following test page to demonstrate the issue:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.panel {
  position: absolute;
  width: 326px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.item-container {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0 none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.item {
  width: 100%;

}
.item.highlighted {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #103e61;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="panel">
    <ul class="item-container">
        <li class="item">Test1</li>
        <li class="item">Test2</li>
        <li class="item">Test3</li>
        <li class="item">Test4</li>
        <li class="item">Test5</li>
        <li class="item">Test6</li>
        <li class="item">Test7</li>
        <li class="item">Test8</li>
        <li class="item">Test9</li>
        <li class="item">Test10</li>
        <li class="item highlighted">Test11</li>
        <li class="item">Test12</li>
        <li class="item">Test13</li>
        <li class="item">Test14</li>
        <li class="item">Test15</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jfvtc1ek/

When opened with Chrome 70.0.3538.77, the "Test11" list element is shown in white when scrolled into view because Chrome does not render the background-color for some reason. It has something to do with the absolute positioning of the parent in combination with the z-index.

The same fiddle works in Firefox so I am not sure if this is a bug in Chrome?

Comment: `.item-container { position: relative; }` or `.item { position: relative; }` seem to fix it.

Comment: Submitted a bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=904370

Answer (score 0):

You are right - probably a bug.

For Chrome:

it is working without position

it is working without z-index

it is working without overflow